# Blackberry Development, communicating two Blackberry device in a multiplayer game programatically

Tags: blackberry, communication, device

We are developing a game application for Blackberry, which will have multi player option to let two or more player compete against each other. We have implemented the logic for that and already two or more player are able to play the game simultaneously on single device.

Now we want to upgrade our application so that two or more user can compete each other playing from different device and different locations.

Can anyone please help me by providing me the way (or code) to achieve this (communicating two blackberry devices over the air to access single session programmaticaly)?

I found the code to connect two device using Bluetooth but as the player may situated in different geographic regions we need to achieve this using over the air connection.

Answer (score 1):

what about pin messaging. after making move of one player send pin messages about his move to other players than read received pin messages through your code using folder listener and change the UI.
pin messaging is free 
but both handset should be blackberry.

Comment: Hi Vivart,

Thanks for taking some time out and looking in to my problem. I have looked in to this earlier but as I am a newbie in this field so I am not sure of how should I implement this. Well I will do some searches about this, meanwhile it would be great if you have any sample code for this which you can provide me.

Well we can send PIN message once the players started the game but how can we bind two different users to the same session, like should we implement some feature that would first have one user send invitation to other player and then they can join the same game session

Answer (score 0):

i have read your article Really Nice one.because Now a days not only big companies like Adobe, Microsoft are doing Blackberry App Development in India at their development center. But now many other small to medium scale companies have started Blackberry Software Development, ipad html5 development and started entering into iPad Web Development. It is considered that, increase in business will be around 100% in Wireless Application Development.